# To explain the need for something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Tip of my tongue here.

"How do you plan to _____ buying all this freight?"

"How can you _____ doing something like that?"

"I can't really _____ buying a car right now."

Closest word I can think of is "advocate", but that's not quiet right.

It's often used in the context of giving yourself a reason of doing something.

Comment: [**justify**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/justify)

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285670/justify-vs-rationalize).

Answer (score 2):

A number of words would work well here. "Justify" is what first comes to mind. Rationalize, explain, warrant, and even support would work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Might the word 'Accomplish' work?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer looks more like a comment than an answer. Please visit this [site](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/answering).

Comment: *Accomplish* would fit in the sentences, but doesn't really mean "giving yourself a reason for buying a car". Please don't answer questions with a question. Provide a definite answer, and corroborate that answer. An "answer" which is a question is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'll go with **legitimize**.

> : to demonstrate or declare to be justified. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/legitimate)
>
> : to show or declare to be legitimate or proper. [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/legitimate)
>
> *That motorcycle you could never legitimize buying but always lusted over is now sitting in their garage* [Journal Of a Mad Man](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OnwNBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22legitimize+buying%22&source=bl&ots=fPMsGXzvDd&sig=ohUcbCjoMyJJQkcJIzRu-TFy3go&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwA2oVChMIq4uE9PWSyQIVhkAaCh0g8AHH#v=onepage&q=%22legitimize%20buying%22&f=false)

Comment: 'I can't really legitimise buying a couple of new fur coats.' Are you saying people really talk like this?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, apparently some people do... http://forums.audioholics.com/forums/threads/clueless-user-budget-pioneer-setup.86883/

Comment: Not a wonderful advert for the usage; another sentence by the same person contains 'to try to alleviate clipping I've yet to turn my receiver passed 50'. But if you insist, I'll remake the obvious point. Are you advising OP to speak like this?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. I would say it's okay in colloquial contexts, sort of like saying "aggravate" for "exasperate." I would not recommend speaking like this iin more formal registers, though...